# XML loses double quotes by saving to file

Tags: xml, t-sql, powershell

i'm trying to create xml-file:

```
    DECLARE @XML as XML = ( Select 
                                 ProductID as "@Item", 
                                 Store as "@Store", 
                                 Price as "@Price",  
                                 Stock as "@Stock" 
                            From ItemsDB
                            FOR XML PATH ('product'), ROOT ('products')
                           );

    DECLARE @xmlChar AS VARCHAR(max) = CAST(@xml AS VARCHAR(max))

    SET @xmlChar = REPLACE(REPLACE(@xmlChar, '>', '^>'), '<', '^<')

    DECLARE @command VARCHAR(8000) = 'powershell -Command "Set-Content-Encoding UTF8 D:\XML\test.xml \"' + @xmlChar + '\""'


   EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
```

}

but the xml-file loses all of double quoters and result looks like this:

```
    <products>
      <product Item=100798 Store=121 Price=118.56 Stock=0.0000/>
      <product Item=101628 Store=401 Price=593.14 Stock=0.0000/>
    </products>
```

where is a way to get xml like this:

```
   <products>
      <product Item="100798" Store="121" Price="118.56" Stock="0.0000"/>
      <product Item="101628" Store="401" Price="593.14" Stock="0.0000"/>
    </products>
```

Comment: Have you tried double double-quotes? `ProductID as ""@Item""`

Comment: Just an idea, but are these numbers(int,numeric,decimal)? or Strings (varchar)

Comment: If I do `PRINT @xmlChar`in SSMS the double quotes are there so I'd guess they are removed by your powershell command

Comment: What if you escape the quotes before executing the powershell command? Something like `REPLACE(@xmlChar, '"', '\"')`.

Comment: can you try using single quotes to wrap the content (the data from xmlchar)? Not sure how to do it in SQL, `DECLARE @command VARCHAR(8000) = 'powershell -Command "Set-Content-Encoding UTF8 D:\XML\test.xml ''' + @xmlChar + '' "'` maybe?

Comment: Interesting problem... Did not do this before... Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @SoloMax, Is this question closed, or do you need further help? If not, please use the accept check below the vote counter to close this, Thx!

Comment: @Shnugo, the story with -path and -value doesn't work on my side. I'm replacing " with ''. By edit XML shows single quotes, but in IE it's shown as double quotes. I'm not an expert of powershell, but your command doesn't work on my side. If you are sure, it's correct, I set your answer as passed. Please check it. Thx!

Comment: @Shnugo, danke sehr fuer deine melding

Comment: @SoloMax, Sie sprechen deutsch? Schön zu lesen! What exactly does *doesn't work on my side* mean? I'll edit my answer... If you want to place a comment it's better to do this below the answer. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with some data of mine... This is the "command" coming back:

```
powershell -Command "Set-Content-Encoding UTF8 D:\XML\test.xml \"^<products^>^<product Item="84519" Store="xyz"/^>^<product Item="260" Store="abc"/^>^</products^>\""
```

- You are using bad escaping (powershell awaits the backtick)
- You must escape the `<` but not the `>`
- I had to escape the spaces too
- Your syntax of powershell command was wrong

This works in my system:

```
DECLARE @XML as XML = 
( Select 'TestItem' as "@Item" 
        ,'TestStore' as "@Store"
FOR XML PATH ('product'), ROOT ('products')
);

DECLARE @xmlChar AS VARCHAR(max) = CAST(@xml AS VARCHAR(max));
SET @xmlChar = REPLACE(REPLACE(@xmlChar, '<', '`<'),' ','` ');

DECLARE @command VARCHAR(8000) = 
'powershell -Command Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -path F:\Daten\testXY.xml -value "' + REPLACE(@xmlChar,'"','`''') + '"';

EXEC xp_cmdshell @command;
```

The result

```
<products><product Item='TestItem' Store='TestStore'/></products>
```

I did not find a way to write the same with double quotes, **but this is - normally - of no importance**. XML can deal with both. You see this, if you open this file with an application (here Visual Studio, Win10/Edge and Chrome):

[image: with Visual Studio]

[image: With Win10/Edge]

[image: or Chrome]

Each application accepts this as valid XML and does not just show the content "as is" but does some kind of interpretation. This should be the proof that this works...